# Metallic Material Reflection - Only showing the shape of light?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

I have a material used for the backdrop along with most objects that are created. Once applied and rendered in Cycles the metallic spots only seem to reflect the square of the area lamp. Screenshot of render below.

[image: Image render]

I've tried multiple light set ups, files and toggling with settings on the lights and materials themselves. If I untick the Glossy tab under Visibility on the lights it removes the squares but also affects the lighting in the scene and none of the metallic dots become visible at all.

Below is a screenshot for the material set up.

[image: Material set up]

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, at first glance I would say this seems pretty normal to me... you've set the roughness to 0 which makes it a mirrorlike surface, the area lamp is the brightest and therefore most prominent reflection and apart from the object itself there is no environment which could be reflected...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, that seems to have resolved my issue, thank you! I'm still getting my head around materials and nodes so glad it was an easy fix!